# Forçar aplicativo android fechar e reiniciar

Tags: android

Queria achar alguma forma que mesmo que o aplicativo seja fechado e reinicie automaticamente de novo.

Não achei nenhum conteúdo que possa me ajuda se alguem souber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que me lembro não tem uma forma de fazer isso, mas pode-se finalizar a activity que você está e iniciar novamente, basicamente essa FLAG limpa as activities empilhadas e inicia aquela que você quiser.

Aconselho dar uma olhada na documentação das FLAGS pode te ajudar em demais dúvidas: [FLAGS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent)

**Como fazer:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SuaActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```